# Explicit cast operator vs as with T

Tags: c#

So, I came across with the following "problem" and I really curious about the reasons behind it.

Consider the following:

```
public class B
{

}

public class A<T>
{
    private void AFunc(T t)
    {
        FuncRequireB((B)t); // Not allowed
        FuncRequireB(t as B); // Allowed
    }

    private void FuncRequireB(B b)
    {

    }
}
```

I know that the elegant solution is to define T as B at the class, but I would like to know why "(B)t" and "t as B" different in this case. I know that "as" is safe, so it can generate just null if convert can not be done, and in the other hand explicit cast throws an exception if the conversion is not successful, but why the compiler should care about this? I see no difference between them in this case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Everything is better with `T`, but then again, I am from the UK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that *usually* a cast can perform a user-defined conversion if the compiler knows about one. For a generic type, the compiler doesn't have that information. If you want to just perform a straight reference conversion cast, you can cast to `object` first:

```
FuncRequireB((B)(object) t);
```

This aspect of the available conversions has never been *very* clear to me, to be honest - but it does work.

Note that if you can constrain `T` to be type compatible with `B` anyway, that would be cleaner. Your type isn't very generic if bits of it will only work for a particular type argument.

Comment: I would argue, though you are correct, that it is rather poor practice and indicates a bad design.

Comment: @JamesRalston: Hence the last paragraph.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to emphasize. double casting is a pretty egregious circumvention of the safety a statically typed language provides you, I really want to emphasize that. The `as` works in different way than an explicit cast does. It returns `null` on an unsuccessful boxing (and null reference exceptions are a whole different subject) but this cast is very dangerous.

Comment: @JamesRalston: It's no more dangerous that a required cast in a non-generic context - casting from `object` to `string`, for example. I'm very aware of what `as` does - and I usually *prefer* casting over `as`, as in my experience when a cast fails, that usually means that the world is in a state that the programmer wasn't prepared for - see http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/. The fact that we're using a generic type parameter isn't really relevant to that - but it *is* relevant to the general design of the generic type.

Comment: You are correct, in the sense of generics. The real use case of `as` or explicit casting would be involved in some kind of change in a dependency that you have no control over, so not _your_ bad design. The advantage of `as` is in the exception. To me the `as` cast more explicitly tells anyone reading the code that it may not be the type you are looking for in addition to allowing for far more efficient error detection (a null reference check is **far** more efficient than exception catching. Explicit casts should be used when _you_ can guarantee for whatever reason that it should be that type

Comment: @JamesRalston: I never suggested catching the exception from a cast - but in my experience, most of the time when you need to cast, you're confident that it *will* be valid, even if you can't guarantee it. If your assumption doesn't hold, an exception is often the best approach. I've seen far too much code (mostly on SO) which uses `as` with a comment that it's "safe" - and then dereferences the result with no checking, leading to a `NullReferenceException` if the conversion failed... and that's much less helpful. Then I've seen `as` used with a check - which just throws an exception itself!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65625/discussion-between-james-ralston-and-jon-skeet).